# How to validate list items and give an error message when false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, variable-assignment

So I'm making a game for my class. It's text based and uses a variety of rooms and items in order to complete the game. I've figured out a way to move in between rooms and to acquire the items. I have an inventory function to remove items from the inventory as well.

I'm having trouble because the rooms don't validate conditionally. If you're in the starting room 'spawn room', then the only valid direction is south. When I input North it SHOULD give a statement and reset the prompt but instead the code breaks with a KeyError: 'North'. Error statements are on line 89 and 56.

Another small issue is with my inventory system. If you don't type in 'Set Down', it still prompts the next if statement.

I've tried making direction not set to the directions for the specific rooms but that doesn't seem to work.
EX. line 92

With the inventory, I've also tried indenting in different ways so that the second print statement only appears IF they type 'Set Down' but the if and while statements didn't work.
EX. line 141

```
import sys


def show_instructions():
   #print a main menu and the commands
   print("Batman Text Based Game")
   print("The Riddler has tied Batman up. You must solve the riddles to win the fight against him.")
   print("Move commands: South, North, East, West, Confirm")

#Rooms no longer contain items because I want the player to be able to drop the items at any point in time.
rooms = {
   'Spawn Room' : { 'South' : 'top of the Hallway'},
   'top of the Hallway' : { 'East' : 'Riddle One', 'West' : 'Riddle Two', 'South' : 'Hallway Two'},
   'Hallway Two' : { 'East' : 'Riddle Three', 'West' : 'Riddle Four', 'North' : 'top of the Hallway', 'South' : 'Hallway Three'},
   'Hallway Three' : { 'East' : 'Riddle Five', 'West' : 'Riddle Six', 'North' : 'Hallway Two', 'South' : 'Hallway Bottom'},
   'Hallway Bottom' : { 'East' : 'Riddle Seven', 'West' : 'Riddle Eight', 'North' : 'Hallway Three', 'South' : 'Boss Room'},
   'Riddle One' : { 'West' : 'top of the Hallway'},
   'Riddle Two' : { 'East' : 'top of the Hallway'},
   'Riddle Three' : { 'West' : 'Hallway Two'},
   'Riddle Four' : { 'East' : 'Hallway Two'},
   'Riddle Five' : { 'West' : 'Hallway Three'},
   'Riddle Six' : { 'East' : 'Hallway Three'},
   'Riddle Seven' : { 'West' : 'Hallway Bottom'},
   'Riddle Eight' : { 'East' : 'Hallway Bottom'},
   'Boss Room': { 'item' : 'The Riddler'} #villain
}
R1 = 'R1' #False
R2 = 'R2' #True
R3 = 'R3' #True
R4 = 'R4' #False
R5 = 'R5' #False
R6 = 'R6' #True
R7 = 'R7' #False
R8 = 'R8' #False

#Functions for directional inputs
def moveroom1(direction, currentroom="Spawn Room"):
    print('Batman leaves the', currentroom)
    if direction == 'South':
        return rooms[currentroom]['South']

def moveroom2(direction, currentroom="Spawn Room"):
    print('Batman leaves the', currentroom)
    if direction == 'East':
        return rooms[currentroom]['East']

def moveroom3(direction, currentroom="Spawn Room"):
    print('Batman leaves the', currentroom)
    if direction == 'West':
        return rooms[currentroom]['West']

def moveroom4(direction, currentroom="Spawn Room"):
    print('Batman leaves the', currentroom)
    if direction == 'North':
        return rooms[currentroom]['North']

show_instructions() #Introduction and instructions
print()

currentroom = 'Spawn Room' #Set the starting room

inventory = [] #Blank inventory for the player to pick up items

direction = '' #input for room change

while direction != 'exit': # What directions are available to travel?
    possible_moves = rooms[currentroom].keys()
    print('Possible moves:', *possible_moves)
    print()

# Prompt a direction, process the answer and inform
    direction = input('Move which direction? ').strip()
    print('You entered: ', direction)
    print()
    if direction == 'South':
        currentroom = moveroom1('South', currentroom)
        #print('You are in the', currentroom)

    if direction == 'East':
        currentroom = moveroom2('East', currentroom)
        #print('You are in the', currentroom)

    if direction == 'West':
        currentroom = moveroom3('West', currentroom)
        #print('You are in the', currentroom)

    if direction == 'North':
        currentroom = moveroom4('North', currentroom)
        #print('You are in the', currentroom)

    if direction != 'North' or 'West' or 'East' or 'South' or 'Inventory' or 'Confirm':
        print('That is not a valid command, try again!')

#Riddles and items are appended in this section. Doesn't break loop
    if currentroom == 'Riddle One':
        print('Riddle One here')
        if 'R1' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R1')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Two':
        print('Insert Riddle two here')
        if 'R2' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R2')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Three':
        print('Insert Riddle three here')
        if 'R3' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R3')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Four':
        print('Insert Riddle four here')
        if 'R4' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R4')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Five':
        print('Insert Riddle five here')
        if 'R5' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R5')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Six':
        print('Insert Riddle six here')
        if 'R6' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R6')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Seven':
        print('Insert Riddle seven here')
        if 'R7' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R7')

    if currentroom == 'Riddle Eight':
        print('Insert Riddle eight here')
        if 'R8' not in inventory:
            inventory.append('R8')
            
#This section is prompted by the player inputting Inventory as a direction
    if direction == 'Inventory':
        print(inventory)
        itemdrop = input('Set Down to set down some items, or enter anything to exit inventory.') #Creates a new input for the decision to drop an item or not
        if itemdrop != 'Set Down' or 'set down':
            print('Are you sure you want to exit the inventory?') #I'm not sure what happens here but there are two inputs that are required to get back into the direction loop
        if itemdrop == 'Set Down' or 'set down':

            tyty = input()
            if tyty == 'R1':
                inventory.remove('R1')
                print('You dropped R1')
            if tyty == 'R2':
                inventory.remove('R2')
                print('You dropped R2')
            if tyty == 'R3':
                inventory.remove('R3')
                print('You dropped R3')
            if tyty == 'R4':
                inventory.remove('R4')
                print('You dropped R4')
            if tyty == 'R5':
                inventory.remove('R5')
                print('You dropped R5')
            if tyty == 'R6':
                inventory.remove('R6')
                print('You dropped R6')
            if tyty == 'R7':
                inventory.remove('R7')
                print('You dropped R7')
            if tyty == 'R8':
                inventory.remove('R8')
                print('You dropped R8')
#while currentroom == 'Boss Room':
    #if inventory != #the right items:
        #print('Batman killed The Riddler with excessive force. You lose')
    #if inventory == #any order of the right combination of things:
        #print('Batman fights the Riddler to victory')
#Game loop
if direction == 'exit':
    print('You have quit the game')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What is `"give a statement"` that you think it should do? When your client enters `North`, you try that anyway.

Comment: When in the first room, the only correct exit is 'South' into the top of the hallway. If a player enters 'North', 'East', or 'West, the program should respond with a message notifying that the move is invalid.
Right now it does nothing with my if statement and just prints an error.

Comment: But you haven't written any code which says that `"the move is invalid"`. Are you talking about `print('That is not a valid command, try again!')`?

Comment: Yes. It's an if statement that has multiple directions set to print the result. I know that isn't room specific because it's being used generally here.
I even made
```while currentroom == 'spawn room':
    if *insert that statement here.```
It seems there is an error in the code itself. I understand the logic of why that exact one isn't functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you only need one `moveroom()` function. Like this:

```py
def moveroom(direction, currentroom="Spawn Room"):
    print('Batman leaves the', currentroom)
    if direction in rooms[currentroom]:
        return rooms[currentroom][direction], direction
    return currentroom, None
```

and it can be used like this:

```py
    direction = input('Move which direction? ').strip()
    print('You entered: ', direction)
    print()
    currentroom, direction = moveroom(direction, currentroom)
    print('You are in the', currentroom)

    if direction not in ['North', 'West', 'East', 'South', 'Inventory', 'Confirm']:
        print('That is not a valid command, try again!')
```